# How to set up Ubuntu system to use DNS on LAN host for local names

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I've set up `dnsmasq` on a Raspberry Pi, and would like all my hosts on the LAN to use it. I have set the Pi's IP address in the router as primary DNS server. However, something in the Ubuntu system is bypassing that.

`$ dig dummyhost @raspberrypi` works.

`$ dig dummyhost @router` works.

`$ dig dummyhost` fails.

Please help: what do I need to configure to make it happen?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Not sure what router you have, but the DNS / DHCP might be easier from the router than the Pihole side.  I have my router send the IP of my PiHole as my first DNS record.  Then I have my router as my second DNS record.  After that I replaced my `/etc/resolv.conf` with the `/run/systemd/resolv/resolv.conf` file instead of the `/run/systemd/resolv/stub-resolv.conf` that way it lists my choice of DNS in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file instead of the `127.0.0.1#53`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding.

FWIW, Xubuntu 22.04.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` was linked to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, so I tried replacing it with `../run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` (note the extra e on `resolv`!) and all then worked perfectly.

One thing that has always puzzled me: since most routers offer DHCP, why do they not also offer DNS for local hostnames, since they have exactly the required data?